# How to properly group mixins in Django app?

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-views, mixins

### Initial situation

I have one app, 'devices' with some views:

```
class DeviceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Device
    form_class = DeviceEditForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(DeviceUpdateView, self).get_form(form_class=None)
        form.fields['beacon'].queryset=Beacon.objects.filter(customer_account=self.request.user.default_customer_account)
        return form

class DeviceCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Device
    form_class = DeviceEditForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(DeviceCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial['customer_account'] = self.request.user.default_customer_account
        return initial

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(DeviceCreateView, self).get_form(form_class=None)
        form.fields['beacon'].queryset=Beacon.objects.filter(customer_account=self.request.user.default_customer_account)
        return form
```

I have another app ('buildings') vith this view:

```
class BuildingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserFormKwargsMixin, CreateView):
    model = Building
    form_class = BuildingEditModelForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(BuildingCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial["customer_account"] = self.request.user.default_customer_account
        return initial
```

### DRY Mixin

Now, I want to factorize my code in order to be more "DRY".

I then create this mixin, in my devices/views.py:

```
class BeaconFilterMixin(object):
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(BeaconFilterMixin, self).get_form(form_class=None)
        form.fields['beacon'].queryset=Beacon.objects.filter(customer_account=self.request.user.default_customer_account)
        return form
```

And my views become:

```
class DeviceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, BeaconFilterMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Device
    form_class = DeviceEditForm


class DeviceCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, BeaconFilterMixin, CreateView):
    model = Device
    form_class = DeviceEditForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(DeviceCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial['customer_account'] = self.request.user.default_customer_account
        return initial
```

Nice and sweet!

### Now the question

I want to do exact same thing and create a "InitialCustomerAccountMixin" that could be used by both 'buildings' and 'devices' apps.

The code will be:

```
class InitialCustomerAccountMixin(object):
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(InitialCustomerAccountMixin, self).get_initial()
        initial['customer_account'] = self.request.user.default_customer_account
        return initial
```

The question is: where do I put my mixins code?
For an 'app-scope' mixin, I get that I should put the code in the views.py or in a mixins.py file in the app.
But for a 'multi-app' mixin, I don't know the design principle to follow.

Comment: This is clearly opinion based, but imo best practice will be to put that mixin in app, which defines `default_customer_account` in user account.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow functional grouping principle (or whatever you call it).

If you have a UI layer in your app, it should have `Mixins` module (package, namespace or whatever). This module should have categories for all mixins use: Auth, Filter, View,... etc. Each category should contain respected mixins.

This is for single-app mixins.

Mixins, you have to share between your applications should be encapsulated into their own module (or whatever Python reusable packages are called). This module should be private to you, should be called appropriately and should be split into sensible categories.